# registration form is not submitting in spring boot and not hitting endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a registration form in `Spring Boot` and thymeleaf but it's not submitting to the database. I even run the debugger mood and it did not hit the endpoints for the registration. Note, that my login and other functionalities work fine. I'm following this [here](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/10/user-registration-module-using-springboot-springmvc-springsecurity-hibernate5-thymeleaf-mysql.html) to create my registration

**How to I get this endpoint to create a new user?**

`register.html`

```html
  <form th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

     <p class="error-message" th:if="${#fields.hasGlobalErrors()}"
      th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('global')}" th:text="${error}">Validation
      error</p>

     <div class="form-group"
      th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}? 'has-error':''">
      <label for="firstName" class="control-label">First name</label> <input
       id="firstName" class="form-control" th:field="*{firstName}" />
      <p class="error-message"
       th:each="error: ${#fields.errors('firstName')}"
       th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group"
      th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}? 'has-error':''">
      <label for="lastName" class="control-label">Last name</label> <input
       id="lastName" class="form-control" th:field="*{lastName}" />
      <p class="error-message"
       th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('lastName')}"
       th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group"
      th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}? 'has-error':''">
      <label for="email" class="control-label">E-mail</label> <input
       id="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" />
      <p class="error-message"
       th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('email')}" th:text="${error}">Validation
       error</p>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group"
      th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}? 'has-error':''">
      <label for="email" class="control-label">Username</label> <input
       id="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}" />
      <p class="error-message"
       th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('username')}" th:text="${error}">Validation
       error</p>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group"
      th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}? 'has-error':''">
      <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label> <input
       id="password" class="form-control" type="password"
       th:field="*{password}" />
      <p class="error-message"
       th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('password')}"
       th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
     </div>
        <!-- 
     
      <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
      <span>Already registered? <a href="/" th:href="@{/login}">Login
        here</a></span>
     </div>
      -->
     <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
     
     </div>

    </form>
```

`controller.java`

```java
@Controller
public class RegisterationController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String getRegisterPage(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.put("user", user);
        return "register";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String postRegister(@RequestBody User user,  BindingResult result) {
        User existingUser = userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if(existingUser != null) {
            result.rejectValue("email", null, "this email is already used");
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "register";
            }
        
        userService.saveNewUser(existingUser);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

`UserService.java`

```java
    public void saveNewUser(User user) {
        User nuser = new User();
        nuser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        nuser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        nuser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        nuser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        nuser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        // TODO: is this how you set the role of the user? 
        nuser.setRoles((Set<Role>) Arrays.asList(new Role("user")));
        userRepository.save(nuser);
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing two things; first, I created a custom  `saveNewUser()`  but JPA manages that better so I changed that to this.

`UserService.java`

```
public User save(User user) {
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role> (Arrays.asList(new Role("user"))));
        return userRepository.save(user);
        
    }
```

I also had to change my endpoint to this

`controller.java`

```
@PostMapping("/register")
    public String postRegister(User user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        userService.save(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and I solved it but adding this annotation `@Transactional` to the saveUser function.

```
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
@Transactional
@Override
public void saveUser(UserDto userDto) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(userDto.getFirstName() + " " + userDto.getLastName());
    user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    // encrypt the password using spring security
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
    
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

And also adding this line to the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
```